# How to detect ContentView visibility change inside a TabbedPage in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a few `ContentViews` and they are inside `ContentPages` that are hosted in a `TabbedPage`.

Every time I change the *active tab*, I should detect the *appearing and disappearing* of a given `ContentView`.

I tried to do it this way:

```
public partial class PartialView: ContentView
{
  public PartialView()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    //this.Focused += (x, y) =>
    //this.MeasureInvalidated += (x, y) =>
    this.PropertyChanged += (x, y) =>
    {
        DoDetection();
    };
  }
 }
```

Unfortunately, all those events run *only once*, so when I get back on the tab, nothing happens.

What else should I try?

Comment: Why not hook into the `CurrentPageChanged` event of the TabbedPage and let all pages act on that?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Thank, I'll do that. If you promote your comment to an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I did! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TabbedPage](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.TabbedPage/) is a inheritance of the [MultiPage](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.MultiPage%601/) which has a CurrentPageChanged event, so why not hook into that?

Then you can let your child pages act on whatever page was selected at that time.

Comment: Thanks @Gerald for sharing the solution. I'm trying to do the same but using Sharpnado Tabs and ViewSwitcher without luck. I will keep trying.